# Delete DNS 'A' Records from Domain Controller using Python

Tags: python, dns

I have a DC with "example.com" and I have many DNS records/FQDNs with 'A' record(Windows Servers).

Ex: `Server1.example.com A 172.3.2.1`

I'm using Python and trying to delete the record (server1).

Unfortunately, its giving me response as `None`.

I am using dnspython library.

```
def DeleteDNSRecords(serverList):
    try:
      for server in serverList:
            updater = update.Update(server,'A')
            response = updater.delete(server,'A')
            print(str(response))
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?